# Не работает модальное окно, если пользователь не авторизован

Tags: javascript, битрикс, google-tag-manager

Bitrix. Модальное окно появляется только, когда пользователь авторизован в админке, в ином случае вылезает пустое окно. в консоле ошибка к коду tag manager, но так и не нашел, где можно отредактировать. В другом темплейте есть этот код, а на рабочем он ведет по ссылке на сам сайт:

```
<noscript>
<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WLX7X43"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

[image: пустая форма]
[image: ошибка в консоли]
[image: уточнение, где ошибка]
[image: возможно нужно найти этот код]

в какую сторону капать?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вы в другом файле указали путь на этот компонент. Рекомендую искать часть этого кода через исходники браузера. И найти местоположение этого кода который даёт доступ только к админке.

```
if($USER->GetID()==859)
```

Возможно это вам может помочь